# Canceling a window resizing operation on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

I sometimes try to resize a window and am not happy about the results. I am looking for a program that would allow me to cancel the previous window resizing operation on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I like the idea Franck... basically an *Undo* operation for a Window resize.  Even better would be multiple levels of *Undo*.